# Apply function to each submatrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm looking for a function in R, like apply, but with submatrixes. I would like to do something like this :

The original matrix :

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

After the function (The mean of each 2x2 blocks) :

```
        [,1]   [,2]  [,3]   [,4]
[1,]    3.5    3.5   11.5   11.5
[2,]    3.5    3.5   11.5   11.5
[3,]    5.5    5.5   13.5   13.5
[4,]    5.5    5.5   13.5   13.5
```

Comment: It is not clear how you selected the 2x2 blocks.  Suppose, if I select  `mean(c(2,6,3,7))[1] 4.5`

Comment: I think the idea is to cut the original matrix into four sub-matrices and replace all values in each sub-matrix by its mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way. It assumes the function being applied returns a scalar, like it is the case with `mean`:

```
A <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
k <- 2L

i <- (row(A) + 1L) %/% k        # row grouping
j <- (col(A) + 1L) %/% k        # col grouping
b <- i + (j - 1L) * max(i)      # block grouping
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    3    3
# [2,]    1    1    3    3
# [3,]    2    2    4    4
# [4,]    2    2    4    4

subA <- split(A, b)             # sub-matrices
subm <- sapply(subA, mean)      # sub-means
out  <- array(subm[b], dim(A))  # final output
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  3.5  3.5 11.5 11.5
# [2,]  3.5  3.5 11.5 11.5
# [3,]  5.5  5.5 13.5 13.5
# [4,]  5.5  5.5 13.5 13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
ind <-  matrix(rep(1:2,each=2),4,4)+rep(c(0,2),each=8)
ave(A,ind)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  3.5  3.5 11.5 11.5
#[2,]  3.5  3.5 11.5 11.5
#[3,]  5.5  5.5 13.5 13.5
#[4,]  5.5  5.5 13.5 13.5
```

#### data

```
A <-  matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
```